# R - extract a cell value using conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to use a specific cell value from my dataframe as an object (for later multiplication with other values in the variable, e.g. I want the content of `def` for the `year`= 2019). I do not want to refer to this value via indexing with row/column numbers (large data set).

---

The following code works for me:

```
def2019 <- df %>%
  subset(year =="2019") %>%
  select(def)
def2019 <- def2019[1,1]
def2019 <- as.vector(def2019$def, mode='numeric') to enable multiplication later
```

**But: it is not very fast and also quite hackish. Is there a more generalizable/elegant solution to this problem?**

---

MRE:

```
df <- tribble(~year, ~value,~def,
              "2017", 1, 0.9,
              "2017", 2, 0.9,
              "2018", 3, 1,
              "2019", 4, 1.1,
              "2019", NA, 1.1,
              "2019", 6, 1.1,
              "2019", 9, 1.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need an efficient option, use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
def2019 <- setDT(df, key = 'year')["2019", .(def = def[1])]$def
```

---

If the column 'year' is `integer` class

```
setDT(df, key = 'year')[.(2019), .(def = def[1])]$def
```

Comment: @Magasinus in your example showed the 'year' as character type.  Please check if that is of type character or integer in your original data.  If that is the case, use `[2019, .(def = ` without quotes

Comment: @Magasinus the issue is that there is a clash with row index and your column value.  We can avoid that with `.(2019)` you get an NA because that row index is not available

Comment: @Magasinus have you tried `setDT(df, key = 'year')[.(2019), .(def = def[1])]$def` the update

Comment: In your tweak, you are specifying `.(2019)` in `j` and not in `i`

Comment: Combined with your edited comment, this works. Thank you very much. I will delete my comments for the sake of clarity. (Exactly, I got rows/columns mixed up at first).